# How to raise jira ticket automatically based on Zephyr test case failed

Tags: jira, zephyr-rtos, jira-zephyr

I am new to Zephyr.
I have a requirement where I need to raise a jira tickets automatically when a test case failed in Zephyr .

Could any one suggest how to do this.